# Не понимаю принцип ProgressIndicator в javafx

Tags: java, javafx

1. Почему он ждёт, пока будет заполнен на 100% и лишь потом обновляется
   с 0% на 100%
2. И второе не по теме. Как изменить надпись "Done" после того, как он
   заполнится на 100%

   ```
   public void start(){
   if(ChoiceRe.getText()=="Обычный"){
       time.progressProperty().bind(progress);
       for(int row=0;row<100;row++){
           try {
               TimeStart=TimeStart+0.01;
               progress.setValue(TimeStart);
               Thread.sleep(27);
           } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: Покажите, пожалуйста, минимальный компилируемый код. Это означает, что код должен компилироваться и там не должно быть лишних элементов.

Comment: 1. где он ждет?
2. тебе необходимо будет переопределить skin для прогресс индикатора, т.е. создать свой индикатор

Comment: Не подскажите, где можно найти информацию о том, как создать свой индикатор?

Comment: @dhred погугли на тему "create custom control javafx skin"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Потому что все выполняется в одном потоке, новое значение будет отрисовано в конце цикла. Чтобы увидеть изменение в динамике нужно цикл крутить в отдельном потоке. В примере используется javafx.concurrent.Task, на проперти progress которого биндится progress ProgressIndicator'а.

   ```
   @Override
   public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
     ProgressIndicator progressIndicator = new ProgressIndicator(0);

     Task<Void> task = new Task<Void>() {

       @Override
       protected Void call() throws Exception {
           double TimeStart = 0d;
           for (int row = 0; row < 100; row++) {
               TimeStart = TimeStart + 0.01;
               updateProgress(TimeStart, 1);
               try {
                   Thread.sleep(27);
               } catch (InterruptedException e) {
               }
           }
           return null;
       }
     };
     progressIndicator.progressProperty().bind(task.progressProperty());

     Executors.newCachedThreadPool().submit(task);

     Scene scene = new Scene(progressIndicator);
     primaryStage.setScene(scene);
     primaryStage.show();
   ```

   }
2. см. com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.ProgressIndicatorSkin, DONE - константа, наверное, можно написать свой скин на базе этого.