# В JavaFX - ProgressIndicator во время выполнения задачи

Tags: javafx, progress-bar

Воспользовался вот этим примером: [пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/474298/%D0%9D%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%8E-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BF-progressindicator-%D0%B2-javafx/474897#474897) Я сделал отдельный класс ImportTask, который выполняет все работу. Работа основной задачи заключается в переносе данных из таблицы Excel (FileChooser позволяет выбрать любой файл*.xlsx) в базу данных для последующей обработки запросами. В окне - при нажатии кнопки Старт - ProgressIndicator застывает (перестаёт крутиться) на время работы задачи (task). Что нужно сделать, чтобы ProgressIndicator крутился параллельно выполнению задачи (task)?

Класс задачи:

```
package utils;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

import javafx.stage.FileChooser;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.DataFormatter;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

import javafx.concurrent.Task;
import org.apache.poi.openxml4j.exceptions.OLE2NotOfficeXmlFileException;

public class ImportTask extends Task<Void>{
        static Connection conn;
    static PreparedStatement pst = null;
    static ResultSet rs = null;
        static int count = 0;

                @Override
                protected Void call() throws Exception {
                    double TimeStart = 0d;            
                    CheckConnection();
        try {
        FileChooser fc = new FileChooser();
        fc.getExtensionFilters().addAll(new FileChooser.ExtensionFilter("Excel file", "*.xls", "*.xlsx"));
        File selectedFile = fc.showOpenDialog(null);
        FileInputStream fileIn = new FileInputStream(selectedFile.getAbsoluteFile());
        DataFormatter formatter = new DataFormatter();
        XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(fileIn);
        XSSFSheet sheet =  wb.getSheetAt(0);
        count = sheet.getLastRowNum();
            System.out.println("Row is = " + count);
        Row row;

                String guery = "insert into patentInfo([cc], [patNumber], [kc], [derivativeFrom], [raiting],..." +
                "values(?,?,?,?,...)";
        pst = (PreparedStatement)conn.prepareStatement(guery);

        for (int i = 1; i <= sheet.getLastRowNum(); i++) {

        row = sheet.getRow(i);

            String cc = formatter.formatCellValue(row.getCell(0));
            String patNumber = formatter.formatCellValue(row.getCell(1));
            String kc = formatter.formatCellValue(row.getCell(2));
            String derivativeFrom = formatter.formatCellValue(row.getCell(3));
            String raiting = formatter.formatCellValue(row.getCell(4));
    ...

        pst.setString(1, cc);
        pst.setString(2, patNumber);
        pst.setString(3, kc);
        pst.setString(4, derivativeFrom);
        pst.setString(5, raiting);
    ...
       pst.execute();
        TimeStart = TimeStart + 0.01;
        updateProgress(TimeStart, 1);
        updateMessage("Количество документов: "+ i);
        } 

DialogManager.showInfoDialog("Информационный диалог", "Информация из Excel файла перенесена в программу");

wb.close();
pst.close();
conn.close();
fileIn.close();

}catch(OLE2NotOfficeXmlFileException ex){
                DialogManager.showInfoDialog("Информационный диалог", "Исходная таблица не EXCEL \n"+"Системное сообщение\n"+ex);
                Logger.getLogger(ImportTask.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            } 
            catch(IllegalStateException ex){
                DialogManager.showInfoDialog("Информационный диалог", "В исходной таблице недопустимые символы \n"+"Системное сообщение\n"+ex);
                Logger.getLogger(ImportTask.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
            catch(NullPointerException ex){
                DialogManager.showInfoDialog("Информационный диалог", "В исходной таблице отсутствуют символы \n"+"Системное сообщение\n"+ex);
                Logger.getLogger(ImportTask.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
            catch (SQLException | FileNotFoundException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(ImportTask.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                DialogManager.showInfoDialog("Информационный диалог", "Невозможно прочитать исходный файл \n"+"Системное сообщение\n"+ex);
                Logger.getLogger(ImportTask.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
            return null;

                }

    private void CheckConnection() {
                    conn = SqlConnection.DbConnector();
        if (conn == null) {
            System.out.println("Соединение с таблицей  не удалось");
            System.exit(1);
        } else {
            System.out.println("Соединение с таблицей  удалось");
        } 
    }
};
```

Контроллер:

```
package com.mycompany.rabcom2maven;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.ProgressIndicator;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import utils.ImportTask;
import utils.RingProgressIndicator;


public class PIController implements Initializable {
    @FXML
    ProgressIndicator progressIndicator = new ProgressIndicator(0);

    @FXML
    private StackPane stackPane;

    @FXML
    private Label piLabel;
    @FXML
    private Button continu;
    @FXML
    private Button start;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {



    }
    @FXML
    private void onActionContinu(){
        Stage stage = (Stage)continu.getScene().getWindow();
        stage.close();
    }

    @FXML
    private void onActionStart(ActionEvent event) {
        onStart();
    }

    private void onStart() {
        ImportTask task = new ImportTask();

            progressIndicator.progressProperty().bind(task.progressProperty());
            piLabel.textProperty().bind(task.messageProperty());
            Executors.newCachedThreadPool().submit(task);
            task.run();

    }
}
```

FXML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import java.net.*?>
<?import java.util.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

<AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" prefHeight="496.0" prefWidth="400.0" styleClass="mainFxmlClass" stylesheets="@../styles/StylesMain.css" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="com.mycompany.rabcom2maven.PIController">
    <stylesheets>
        <URL value="@/styles/ringprogress.css" />
    </stylesheets>
   <children>
      <StackPane fx:id="stackPane" layoutX="50.0" layoutY="52.0" prefHeight="300.0" prefWidth="300.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="48.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="50.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="50.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="52.0">
         <children>
            <ProgressIndicator fx:id="progressIndicator" prefHeight="295.0" prefWidth="300.0" progress="0.0" />
         </children></StackPane>
      <Label fx:id="piLabel" layoutX="82.0" layoutY="377.0" prefHeight="35.0" prefWidth="250.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="84.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="82.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="68.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="377.0" />
      <Button fx:id="continu" layoutX="157.0" layoutY="448.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#onActionContinu" text="Продолжить" />
      <Button fx:id="start" layoutX="174.0" layoutY="14.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#onActionStart" text="Старт" />
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Comment: `updateProgress(i, sheet.getLastRowNum());`

Comment: @Andrey M Увы ничего не изменилось. После запуска задачи progressIndicator замирает. После выполнения задачи появляется "успешное завершение".

Comment: Возможно проблема в способе запуска. В официальной документации для `Task` написано `Thread th = new Thread(task);  th.setDaemon(true);  th.start();`. Попробуйте так. Точного ответа дать не могу, т.к. обычно использую `Service` из того же пакета.